# Cancel key up event codes in key down event codes

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code:

```
    $(textBoxElement).keydown(function(e)
 {
  if(e.keyCode==40)
   {
    //some codes
    //cancel key up event 
   }
 }
)
 $(textBoxElement).keyup(function()
  {
    //some codes
  }
```

I want user when pressing down arrow key  keyup event codes don't run

`return false;` and `e.stopPropagation;` dont work.

Comment: `return false` and `e.stopPropagation` don't work because keyup and keydown are different events.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The event will still be triggered, there is no way to prevent the event from firing - but what you **can** change, is how you handle that event. Take the following code for example:

```
var disableKeyUp = false;
$(textBoxElement).keydown(function(e) {
  disableKeyUp = true
})
$(textBoxElement).keyup(function(e) {
  if (!disableKeyUp) {
    // handle keyup event behavior
  }
})
```

We are using a boolean variable to disable the keyup behavior because only when `disableKeyUp` is set to `false`, the keyup event behavior will happen.

Don't forget to re-enable the keyup behavior when you do need it :)

Comment: You are most welcome @MahdiClash :) Glad to help! Happy coding!